# Gives Error when tries to run the code again with updated table in sql-server

Tags: python, sql-server, database, postgresql, database-migration

#This code copies all the data from a single table in sql server to postgres.
#but it only works once. please check

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import io
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
server='NEW'
db1 = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + server + '/' + 'testdb' + '?driver=SQL+Server')
db2 = psycopg2.connect(database="mockdb", user="postgres", password="code123", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM employees"

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, db1, chunksize = 500000):
  chunk.columns = map(str.lower, chunk.columns)

  # Prepare data
  output = io.StringIO()
  chunk.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, encoding="utf8", index=False)
  output.seek(0)
  

  # Inserting  data into postgres

  cursor = db2.cursor()
  cursor.copy_from(output, 'sample_table', sep='\t', null='')
  db2.commit()
  cursor.close()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Is it a constraint violation?  If you intend to copy the entire table again, then you need to truncate `sample_table` before you run the `copy_from`.

Comment: This is the error------psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sample_table_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (employee_id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY sample_table, line 1

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you run this program a second time?

Comment: Hello mike. what i want the code to is to copy the updated data from ms sql to postgres as well

Comment: That requires a lot more coding on your side.  I recommend using a landing table in PG, loading to that, and then updating your main table from the landing table.  To clarify:  Truncate and reload requires only that you add the truncate step.  Synchronizing the table requires writing what I described.

Comment: suppose i made  a change in the name then i want the code to update that in postgres

Comment: Alright! thanks for the help mike.